# "sudo pip install Django" => sudo: pip: command not found

Tags: python, django, terminal, installation

This what my terminal is saying when trying to install Django.

```
MacBook-XXXX:~ Stephane$ sudo pip install Django
sudo: pip: command not found
```

I have tested in idle shell if pip is installed:

```
>>> import easy_install
>>> import pip
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pip` is not a module. It is a command line tool that can be used after installing using the script from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Comment: shall I copy-paste the code in idle and run it?

Comment: Which os Are you on?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: Ios Yosemite: 10.10.2
Idle: Python Version 3.4.3

Comment: @Sulot No, you run the file after saving it. Use `python get-pip.py`.

Comment: Hum. I guess Thomas answer worked.

    MacBook-Stephane:~ Stephane$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.8
    MacBook-Air-de-Stephane:~ Stephane$

Comment: Now it is installed but, I cannot import it...!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to install pip

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: Seems it has been working! Thanks. The thing is I am a beginer and I don't get when I have to type in idle shell or terminal shell. Tks.

Also it was installed for python 2.7, but my idle is python 3.4. So when I import django=> not working.

Comment: For python3 do you need to use pip3 e.g. `sudo pip3 install django`

Answer (score 2):

`pip` is a package management system used for installing packages written in python. So first install `pip` and then `Django`.

`sudo apt-get install python-pip.`

And for installing `django`, follow 
[django installation steps.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/install/)

Comment: MacBook-XXXX:~ Stephane$  - no apt-get on OSX

Comment: @PaulHargreaves His answer was helpful to those who are not slaves to apple.