# Adding "sudo" before a command makes the command unknown

Tags: python, linux, root, redhat, sudo

This is a linux problem that's been stumping me for a while. On my work linux box (running RedHat) I was trying to install some Python packages. However, some funny business is occurring, see below:

1. This is my objective and first command

   ```
   pip install scrapylib
   ```
2. This creates a 'Permission Denied' error

   ```
   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapylib'
   ```
3. My knee-jerk reaction is to put "sudo" in front of the exact same command...

   ```
   sudo pip install scrapylib
   ```
4. That generates this exception,

   ```
   sudo: pip: command not found
   ```
5. In order to get around this, I type

   ```
   sudo su - root
   ```
6. Now this command runs 100% successfully

   ```
   pip2.7 install scrapylib
   ```
7. Finally, I change back to me

   ```
   sudo su - uspowpow
   ```

Can anyone explain this phenomenon to me? I'm a recent college grad with nothing other than basic Linux knowledge, if someone could explain why placing "sudo" in front of a valid command makes it invalid, I would be extremely grateful (both for the fix and for the knowledge).

Comment: Try `sudo /path/to/pip` instead.

Comment: Depends on the details, but keep in mind that `sudo` is often configured to force a known-safe set of environment variables, including PATH. This is an important security feature -- think of what happens if you only have someone allowed to run commands off a short whitelist if they can install environment variables that modify how those commands behave.

Comment: BTW, this isn't really a programming question; it would be a better fit for http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that alias expansion does not work by default when using sudo.

Comment: @pzp, not just "by default"; in most shells, alias expansion doesn't work at all for anything not in the very first position. zsh is one of the very few exceptions I know of where it's even possible to configure anything else. (Or are you referring to alias expansion being off by default in noninteractive shells, *and* noninteractive shells not sourcing configuration files where aliases are typically defined? In that latter case, it would only matter if `sudo` were launching a shell, which it doesn't by default without `-i` or `-c`).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514136/sudo-pip-install-django-sudo-pip-command-not-found

Comment: BTW, @uspowpow, re (7), it would be better to change back to you by running `exit`. As it is, you're still leaving your root shell open and accessible -- if you run `pstree`, you'll see the original shell as you, then the shell as root, and then a new shell all still running after following the steps you gave here.

Comment: As an aside -- running pip as root isn't a great practice in the first place. Consider using `virtualenv` to sandbox your installation of 3rd-party Python libraries; that way you can have a different set of libraries installed for each Python project you're working on. Also, put the virtualenv in your home directory, and you don't need any permissions other than running as yourself to install new packages into it.

Comment: ^ Awesome point @CharlesDuffy, thank you

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the advice about virtulenv and placing it in my home directory. I will absolutely do that going forward. Moreover, I realize "running pip as root isn't a great practice in the first place." That's the whole point of this post haha. What can I do to solve this? What is the root cause of the problem? Is my command not in the PATH enforced by sudo? If so, how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: All programs, including `sudo`, use the PATH to find the location of programs to execute when you don't fully qualify them. That's why my answer's suggestions revolve around fully qualifying the PATH when passing it to sudo.

Comment: Well -- the above isn't *quite* accurate; let me be more precise: In general, a program that needs to run other programs but doesn't know their exact location will use `execvp()` or `execlvp()` syscalls to run that program, and the operating system (or the C library) will do a lookup in the PATH to find it in the course of that function's execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen for several reasons. To pick a few:

- Your command may not be in the PATH enforced by `sudo`. For a command in `/usr/local/bin` (where your `pip` appears to be), this is downright likely.
- Your command may require an alias or shell function to be valid (perhaps you have `pip` aliased to `pip2.7`?), or may be a shell builtin itself (though this wouldn't be the case for `pip`). By default `sudo` directly invokes children using a member of the execv* family of syscalls, with no shell, so (1) shell functions and aliases aren't invoked under it all; and (2) even if you *were* using a shell, that shell wouldn't run your current user's dotfiles (being a noninteractive shell, if given a single command to run, it won't run *most* dotfiles).

---

To know what the *actual* cause is, the place to start is to find out what kind of command `pip` is. To do this, run:

```
$ type pip
```

If the answer you get is:

```
pip is /usr/local/bin/pip
```

...then you should look at the `secure_path` value set in your `/etc/sudoers` to ensure that it contains `/usr/local/bin`, or just run `sudo /usr/local/bin/pip` to sidestep the issue. By contrast, if you get:

```
pip is aliased to `pip2.7'
```

...then you know the problem is that it's an alias, and you need to run `sudo pip2.7` (if the PATH is not *also* a problem).

Comment: Neither of those exact cases happened when I typed "type pip." Here is my output: pip is hashed (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip)

Comment: `sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip`, then.

Comment: When trying this ^ it throws an error saying "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip: command not found"

Comment: the full command was "sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip install numpy"

Comment: That can't be right. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` is a MacOS path. You said you're running Red Hat. Maybe you ran the `type pip` command in the wrong window?

Comment: You're awesome. I absolutely typed it into the wrong window. `type pip` now returns `pip is /usr/local/bin/pip`. Does this give you insight on how to fix my path or what action to take to prevent me from having to type the full path/to/pip

Comment: I already told you how to fix your PATH in that situation; edit the `secure_path` setting in your `sudoers` file. See `man sudoers` to find the appropriate format for the version of `sudo` you're running, and consider using `visudo` to run an automatic syntax check before saving changes (to avoid locking yourself out with an invalid file).

Comment: Just digested everything you had to say and you were spot-on, simply adding /usr/local/bin to my SECURE_PATH variable (via visudo) was all that I needed to do. THANK YOU!